# Finding the number of occurrences of an element in every list inside a list

Tags: python, list, nested, position

Here I have a nested list:

```
[['a,b,c,d,e’], [‘d,e,c,b,a’], [‘e,b,a,e,c’], ['a,c,b,e,d'], [‘e,d,c,b,a’], [‘a,c,b,d,e']]
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of "a" in the beginning of each list, so that will be 3. I also want to be able to do the same for each letter in the lists, so I know that the number of "b" in the second position of each list is 2.
This is perhaps easier to imagine if you put each list on top of each other and look down the column.

I want to be able to give the letter and position to scan through and receive the number of occurrences of that letter in that position. I hope I'm clear.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
number=sum(x.count("a") for x in data[0][0])
```

Comment: Yes. You are clear. What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: How can you use three different "quote" characters, inconsistently, and two of them invalid?

Comment: I guess, this was just copied from some book/formatted doc

Comment: I'm a beginner so i tried using list[0][0] but I'm not sure if I am on the right track or if I should be doing something completely diffrent

Comment: you wrote ` tried using list[0][0]` - post that code

Comment: Yes I copied it from word sorry if the formatting is a bit wrong

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: elaborate whether this `'a,b,c,d,e’` is actually presented as `['a','b','c','d','e']` ?

Comment: No, they are all one string. Do I need to separate them in order for this to work?

Comment: Instead of staying sorry, better simply fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most simple case you may use the following:

```
data = [['a,b,c,d,e'], ['d,e,c,b,a'], ['e,b,a,e,c'], ['a,c,b,e,d'], ['e,d,c,b,a'], ['a,c,b,d,e']]
letter = 'b'
pos = 1
result = sum(1 for i in data if letter in i[0] and i[0].split(',')[pos] == letter)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
2
```

---

To get a more accurate and robust solution:

```
data = [['a,b,c,d,e'], ['d,e,c,b,a'], ['e,b,a,e,c'], ['a,c,b,e,d'], ['e,d,c,b,a'], ['a,c,b,d,e']]
letter = 'b'
pos = 1
result = 0

for i in data:
    if letter in i[0]:
        items = i[0].split(',')
        if pos < len(items) and items[pos] == letter:
            result += 1

print(result)
```

Comment: If you want "most simple", why do you include `letter in i[0] and `? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function instead of just loops. Because it's easier to give a parameter as index no and letter:

Here is solution with a function:

```
list_1= [['a,b,c,d,e'], ['d,e,c,b,a'], ['e,b,a,e,c'], ['a,c,b,e,d'], ['e,d,c,b,a'], ['a,c,b,d,e']]

    def find(index,letter,list_1):
        count=0
        for item in list_1:
            for subitem in item:
                if subitem[index]==letter:
                    count+=1
        return count
```

> Test with 'a' with index 0:

```
print(find(0, 'a', list_1))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Test with 'b' with index 2:

```
print(find(2, 'b', list_1))
```

Output:

```
2
```